# How import model from forge scene to map(Google, arcGis etc)?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I use forge API in my application. I added an arcGis map to display the model using the methods from the post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dump-geometries-2d-curve in GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT. 
When I work with small models, the data is displayed on the ArcGis map well, but info about layers are lost. 
When the models are large, I get a very large data object(100mb + ) and my program does not work. Is it possible to save the model in threejs-friendly formats or to get a more compact object with model and layers data? Or are there still ways to display the model on the map? I would be very grateful for the advice.

I tried methods from the post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dump-geometries-2d-curve in GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your use case, but I've been working on a tool for converting Forge models into glTF format (which is pretty three.js-friendly I'd say): https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-extract.

Comment: Note: currently the tool only exports 3D content but 2D is a [work-in-progress](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-extract/issues/4).

Comment: thank you very much! It's a cool program, now I can covert CAD to gltf.

Comment: Answer me 2 more questions please)                                                                                       
if my CAD .dwg drawing is in 2d format, can I just save it in 3d and then convert it to gltf? Or something like that)                                                                          And can I save models in .glb (not gltf + bin because then there are moments with import.)

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to convert 2D primitives into 3D primitives (triangular meshes). Even if there is, I wouldn't suggest that approach as the complexity of the resulting 3D content could explode.